# Flutter - always routing to '/' route first on app restart even though `initialRoute` is something else

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I am making a flutter app where i am handling routing and navigation using the `onGenerateRoute` in main app where I am passing the following :

```
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    debugPrint('ROUTING TO ${settings.name}');    
    switch (settings.name) {
      case HomeScreen.id:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const HomeScreen());
      case EditProfileScreen.id:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) =>
                EditProfileScreen(user: settings.arguments as User));
      case FollowerFollowingScreen.id:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) =>
                FollowerFollowingScreen(userId: settings.arguments as String));
      case ThreadScreen.id:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => ThreadScreen(
                  post:
                      (settings.arguments as ThreadNavigationArguments).parent,
                  isParentAComment:
                      (settings.arguments as ThreadNavigationArguments)
                          .isParentAComment,
                  postId:
                      (settings.arguments as ThreadNavigationArguments).postId,
                ));
      case ProfileScreen.id:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => ProfileScreen(user: settings.arguments as User),
        );

      case LoginScreen.id:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const LoginScreen());
      case SettingsScreen.id:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const SettingsScreen());
      case ChooseTopicScreen.id:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const ChooseTopicScreen());
      case AddPostBody.id:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => AddPostBody(user: settings.arguments as User));

      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => Scaffold(
                  body: Center(
                    child: Text('No route for ${settings.name}'),
                  ),
                ));
    }
  }
```

Also in `iniTialRoute` I have passed `jwtToken != null && jwtToken!.isNotEmpty ? HomeScreen.id : LoginScreen.id` . `HomeScreen.id` is `'/'` while `LoginScreen.id` is `/login` . However whenever app is restarting (without loggin in) or when app starts for the first time, it is first routing to `/` and then to `/login` as evident from the statement which i printed in the console

[image]

So the problem happening is the on hitting back on login screen I am going to home screen as / is below /login in the stack. And on app restart it is always first routing to `/` (and not necessarily HomeScreen.id which is also `/`, as I checked by setting it to `/home`) and then going to `/login`. why is this occurring even though I have set `initialRoute` appropriately? Any fixes?

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that your route name is treated as a deep link if it starts with a slash and therefor all previous routes are also pushed as well.

You could change your route names so that they dont start with a slash, or override **onGenerateRoute** of the **MaterialApp** to return your first route inside of a **List** of **Routes** instead.

This is a small example that shows both ways (you can use either one):

```
void main() => runApp(_build());

Widget _page(String txt, String navigateTo) {
  return Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(navigateTo),
        child: Text("this is $txt and goes to $navigateTo"),
      ),
    );
  });
}

Widget _build() {
  return MaterialApp(
    initialRoute: "a/login",
    onGenerateInitialRoutes: (String initialRoute) => <Route<dynamic>>[
      MaterialPageRoute<Widget>(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return _page("/initial", "a/login");
      }),
    ],
    onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
      print("ROUTING TO ${settings.name}");
      if (settings.name == "a/") {
        return MaterialPageRoute<Widget>(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return _page("a/", "a/login");
        });
      } else if (settings.name == "a/login") {
        return MaterialPageRoute<Widget>(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return _page("a/login", "a/");
        });
      } else {
        return MaterialPageRoute<Widget>(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(),
            body: const Text("no page"),
          );
        });
      }
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my application, as i came to know `MaterialApp` do add the `/` in the stack initially after your defined screen added to the stack. and if you press back button it pops you added screen and as the `/` is still in the stack it will be showed.

Simplest fix is to make new screen for '/' with any name like InitScreen and use `Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil()` from there.

You can do your ternary operation for next screen there `jwtToken != null && jwtToken!.isNotEmpty ? HomeScreen.id : LoginScreen.id`